# Fetch Error in Log file between two timestamps in power shell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

My log file looks like : Service.log file

```
2020-08-14 00:10:48,007 INFO RuleExecutor - Assembly resolution for :hsshh
2020-08-14 00:10:55,037 INFO RuleExecutor - Assembly resolution for : abscd
2020-08-14 00:10:56,042 INFO RuleExecutor - Assembly resolution for : ERROR VHAH
2020-08-14 00:10:57,042 INFO RuleExecutor - Assembly resolution for : ERROR Aaaa
2020-08-14 00:11:50,112 INFO chcvjhg - XXXXXXX
```

Problem statement: between two time stamp 2020-08-14 00:10:55 and 2020-08-14 00:11:50 i want the to fetch the record which have keyword like "ERROR"

I am very new to PowerShell, can anyone help me here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't tag `powershell-2.0` and `powershell-3.0`, as those are version dependent tags. Use those only, if target platform is going to be such an old one.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily the timestamp in your log format is sortable, so you can just use regular comparison operators (like `-gt`/`-lt`):

```bsh
$start = '2020-08-14 00:10:55'
$end   = '2020-08-14 00:11:50'

Get-Content Service.log |Where-Object {
  ($_ -gt $start) -and ($_ -lt $end) -and ($_ -like '*error*')
}
```

Comment: $ErrorData = Get-Content  $LogFilePath + "\" + $Name |Where-Object {}